# Tensorflow restoring named variables

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am building a convolutional neural network with Tensorflow.

```
def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial,name = 'weights')

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial, name = 'biases')

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.name_scope('convolution1'):
        W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 96*96])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 30])
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,96,96,1])

    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    with tf.name_scope('convolution2'):
        W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    with tf.name_scope('connected'):
        W_fc1 = weight_variable([24 * 24 * 64, 1024])
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 24*24*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    with tf.name_scope('output'):
        W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 30])
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([30])
```

After this i do some computation and training and save all the variables.

Now i recreate the same graph structure in another program

**PROGRAM 2 snippet**

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 96*96])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,96,96,1])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 30])

with tf.name_scope('convolution1'):
    W_conv1 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'weights')
    b_conv1 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'biases')

with tf.name_scope('convolution2'):
    W_conv2 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'weights')
    b_conv2 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'biases')

with tf.name_scope('connected'):
    W_fc1 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'weights')
    b_fc1 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'biases')

with tf.name_scope('output'):
    W_fc2 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'weights')
    b_fc2 = tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape = False, name = 'biases')

session = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(session, 'my-model-2000')
vars_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 24*24*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
y_convtry = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2
y_conv_alternate = 95.99*tf.ones_like(y_convtry)
y_conv = tf.select(tf.greater(y_convtry, y_conv_alternate), y_conv_alternate, y_convtry)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.select(tf.is_nan(y_), y_conv, y_) - y_conv), reduction_indices=[1])))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cost,var_list = vars_list)
```

The problem is the variables in vars_list when i try to get their shape they still show none,
but running:

```
vars_list[i].eval(session = session)
```

is giving the correct answer so the restoration is working.

My question is why isn't vars_list[i].get_shape() giving the wrong answer tf.shape(vars_list[i]) doesn't seem to work either.

This is a problem because when i use

```
tf.AdamOptimizer.minimize(cost) //This internally call var.get_shape() and throws error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `validate_shape=False` on creating a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable), this tells TensorFlow that the variable can contain any shape of data, and allows you (for example) to restore arbitrarily shaped checkpoint data into the variables. However, this provides TensorFlow with no static information about the shapes of the variables, which (for example) `AdamOptimizer.minimize()` uses to build appropriately shaped accumulator slots.

The best solution would be to reuse the same code for creating variables that you used in the first program, i.e.

```
with tf.name_scope('convolution1'):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
```

...and so on. The initialization functions for these variables will never be run, so there is no additional cost to writing it this way.

Comment: Yeah, this works, but this is really a cumbersome way to restore models, i hope they come up with a better way.

Comment: The `MetaGraphDef` is designed as a serialization format for entire models, include the model structure and checkpoints, and it is a less cumbersome way of doing what you're trying to do. Take a look at the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html) for more details.